# how to create htaccess to modifies url with 2 parameter

Tags: .htaccess

Please someone help me to edit my htaccess.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^supplyer/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) supplyer.php?page=$1&id=$2 [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

What I want:
1. every file .php remove .php
rewrite URL
2. supplyer.php?page=edit&id=120 to supplyer/edit/120

for the fist one it work properly but the second it not work someone help me.

Answer (score 0):

To match the `/supplyer/edit/120` uri string , your pattern should be `^supplyer/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9]+)`

Try :

```
RewriteRule ^supplyer/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ supplyer.php?page=$1&id=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: RewriteRule ^supplyer/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ supplyer.php?page=$1&id=$2 [NC,L] When I try this it work but it is missing style and script

Comment: Now I found the soludtion RewriteRule ^supplyer-([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)-([0-9]+)/?$ supplyer.php?page=$1&id=$2 [NC,L] Thans for your answer